Invariance of condensed sets to the underlying site
Consider Scholze's lecture notes on condensed mathematics (https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf), lecture II, proposition 2.3 and 2.7. We have an uncountable strong limit cardinal $\kappa$ and consider the sites $\text{ExDisc}_\kappa$, $\text{ProFin}_\kappa$ and $\text{CHaus}_\kappa$ of extremally disconnected, totally disconnected and plain compact Hausdorff spaces equipped with finite, jointly surjective families as covers. The claim is now, that all three sites give rise to the same topos $\text{CondSet}_\kappa$ of $\kappa$-condensed sets (given by restricting the sheaves along the inclusions of the categories).
Lets focus on the first equivalence $i_\ast\colon\text{Sh}(\text{CHaus}_\kappa)\to\text{Sh}(\text{ProFin}_\kappa)$ given by the map of sites $i\colon\text{CHaus}_\kappa\to\text{ProFin}_\kappa$ induced by the full inclusion of underlying categories.
In the notes Scholze argues as follows: Let $T$ be a sheaf on $\text{CHaus}_\kappa$. Every $S$ compact Hausdorff admits a surjection $S'\to S$ from a profinite (even extremally disconnected) space. Since this is a cover of $S$ we must have that
$$T(S)\to T(S')\rightrightarrows T(S'\times_SS')$$
must be an equalizer by the sheaf condition. Hence the values $T(S)$ must be already determined by the values $T(S')$ and $T(S'\times_S S')$ of $T$ on $\kappa$-small profinite sets. This easily implies the proposition.
I understand all of the argumentation that is explicitly spelled out. I am however unable to complete this proof on a formal level. How do we show that $i_\ast$ is an equivalence, using this property?
To me this shows that $i_\ast$ must conservative. If $T\to T'$ is a morphism of sheaves such that $i_\ast T \to i_\ast T'$ is an iso, so is the original one: Essentially by this argument above and using that the surjection $S'\to S$ is actually functorial (its the Stone-\v Cech compactifaction of the discretization of $S$). I feel like this is the essence of what was shown.
I think I am also able to show that $i^{-1}$ must be fully faithful and since $i^{-1}$ must be the inverse of $i_\ast$ (by uniqueness of adjoints) if(!) $i_\ast$ is an equivalence, this seems good to know. I am however not 100% confident in the argumentation.
To see this consider component $T'\to i_\ast i^{-1} T'$ of the unit at a sheaf $T'$ on $\text{ProFin}_\kappa$. It should be (up to the isomorphism $T'\to (T')^\#$) the sheafification of the morphism $T'\to i_\ast i^{-1}_p T'$ where $i_p^{-1}$ is $i^{-1}$ before sheafification. But for some profinite $S'$ the component at $S'$ is simply the natural morphism
$$T'(S') \to (i_\ast i_p^{-1} T')(S') = (i_p^{-1}T')(S')=\varinjlim_{S'\to S} T'(S)$$
which should be an isomorphism since $S'\to S'$ is initial in the index category. So this and hence its sheafification and hence the postcomposition with $T'\to (T')^\#$ must have all be isos. As $T'$ was arbitrary the unit is an iso and finally $i^{-1}$ fully faithful.
Are these two properties ($i_\ast$ conservative and $i^{-1}$ fully faithful) maybe enough to deduce equivalence? Even if so: If there maybe an easier way to see this? At least by the way the proof is written up, it seems the equivalence should be a purely formal conseqeunce.

Can you add a link to the lecture notes? Thanks!

Of course, said and done.

The most convenient proof I know is by checking that theses subcategories define bases as in https://people.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Conceptual.pdf, Proposition B.6.4. I guess the argument in condensed.pdf at least indicates the idea that one can reconstructs a sheaf by only knowing its values on profinites and taking some sort of limit construction but I'm not sure how much work one really needs to make that rigorous (besides the thing I quoted).

Thanks for the pointer! Bases/dense-sub-sites indeed are a good hint. I will give Lurie's a read and also take a look at Sketches of an Elephant if I get my hands on that. C.f. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+sub-site#JTT02
